# What should I do 1st, gaussian, or median filter, to clean noise?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

Assuming both white noise, and salt and pepper, which filter should I apply 1st - Gaussian, or median?

Median is nonlinear, thus order does matter.

Comment: There's no point in applying a Gaussian filter once you've applied the median filter. The median filter will reduce both types of noise.

Comment: What is your goal by combining those two? They do not really go well together in the first place since they work quite differently - think about smoothing vs. edge preservation.

Comment: Show your input image!

Answer (score -1):

Apply median blurring first.

Median blur is useful for removing salt and pepper noise, and Gaussian filtering for removing Gaussian noise. Your image may contain both types, so applying both filters may be appropriate in some cases.

Median filtering removes the extreme outliers present in salt and pepper noise, therefore allowing Gaussian blurring to work more effectively.

Comment: The median filter is quite effective at removing Gaussian noise, uniformly distributed noise, Poisson noise, or any other type of noise that is uncorrelated between pixels. The Gaussian filter is great too for any noise type, but as a linear filter is limited in that it will blur the image more. In any case, there is no point in using both at the same time.